# Which is suitable fragmentation style for Distributed DBMS architecture with Micro-service oriented application?

Tags: database-design

I am new to Distributed DB design. In my current application ,I am having multiple functionalities which shares the some common tables from DB. All these functionalities will be build in spring, spring boot using Micro-Services architecture. Most of the functionality shares the same tables which can not be put in separate database.
I have searched about the Distributed DBMS design. So i need to follow either Vertical fragmentation or Horizontal fragmentation.

1. If I will follow the vertical approach, then does it will create any issue for Joining the tables through micro-services which are in different DB's?
2. If I will follow the Horizontal approach, then almost all functionality tables will resides in Same DB. Then Can I get the advantage of distributed DB, as my all tables will be in same DB?

Comment: It depends on the scale of the target system and what are the features most commonly used. If the end-end demands features that involves lots of joins across multiple tables to serve a single query, then it is better to shard the database. If the micro-services are going to operate quite independent, then a vertical design makes sense, since the services have all the data local to a few tables in the same DB and these DBs can be scaled independently.

I am a big proponent of horizontal sharding, since that gives you lots of flexibility for future

Comment: Read this if you are interested in how Pinterest scaled MySQL horizontally: https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL 9.6. Here I got confused now, Sharding is similar to Fragmentation or itself an alternative name to it. Please clear my Confusion.